# Efficient way to append dataframes below each other

Tags: python, pandas, append, concatenation

I have the following part of code:

```
for batch in chunk(df, n):
    unique_request = batch.groupby('clientip')['clientip'].count()
    unique_ua = batch.groupby('clientip')['name'].nunique()
    reply_length_avg = batch.groupby('clientip')['bytes'].mean()
    response4xx = batch.groupby('clientip')['response'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.startswith(str(4)).sum())
```

where I am extracting some values based on some columns of the DataFrame `batch`. Since the initial DataFrame `df` can be quite large, I need to find an efficient way of doing the following:

1. Putting together the results of the for loop in a new DataFrame with columns `unique_request`, `unique_ua`, `reply_length_avg` and `response4xx` at each iteration.
2. Stacking these DataFrames below of each other at each iteration.

I tried to do the following:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame()
    
for batch in chunk(df, n):
    unique_request = batch.groupby('clientip')['clientip'].count()
    unique_ua = batch.groupby('clientip')['name'].nunique()
    reply_length_avg = batch.groupby('clientip')['bytes'].mean()
    response4xx = batch.groupby('clientip')['response'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.startswith(str(4)).sum())
    concat = [unique_request, unique_ua, reply_length_avg, response4xx]
    df_final = pd.concat([df_final, concat], axis = 1, ignore_index = True)
    
return df_final
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Any idea of what should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all avoid using pd.concat to build the main dataframe inside a for loop as it gets exponentially slower. The problem you are facing is that `pd.concat` should receive as input a list of dataframes, however you are passing [df_final, concat] which, in essence, is a list containing 2 elements: one dataframe and one list of dataframes. Ultimately, it seems you want to stack the dataframes vertically, thus `axis` should be `0` and not `1`.

Therefore, I suggest you to do the following:

```
df_final = []

for batch in chunk(df, n):
    unique_request = batch.groupby('clientip')['clientip'].count()
    unique_ua = batch.groupby('clientip')['name'].nunique()
    reply_length_avg = batch.groupby('clientip')['bytes'].mean()
    response4xx = batch.groupby('clientip')['response'].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.startswith(str(4)).sum())
    concat = pd.concat([unique_request, unique_ua, reply_length_avg, response4xx], axis = 1, ignore_index = True)
    df_final.append(concat)

df_final = pd.concat(df_final, axis = 0, ignore_index = True)
    
return df_final
```

Note that `pd.concat` receives a list of dataframes and not a list that contains a list inside of it! Also, this approach is way faster since the `pd.concat` inside the for loop doesn't get bigger every iteration :)

I hope it helps!

Comment: I think that this line `df_final += [unique_request, unique_ua, reply_length_avg, response4xx]` does not do what I need, since it stacks horizontally the features per iteration and not vertically.

Comment: That line is not stacking horizontally :) It is just creating a list with all the features of every iteration. After the for loop it stacks everything vertically

Comment: The thing is that finally I need a dataframe that has N rows and 4 columns and not 4xN rows and 1 column. With this way I am getting a dataframe with 4xN rows and 1 column.

Comment: Got it, give me 1 sec :)

Comment: @Kosmylo everyhing okay? Note that the use of pd.concat now inside the for loop is okay. I have explained it in the answer :)